# Ubuntu not accepting some TCP/IP connections

Tags: ubuntu, networking, docker

So I am absolutely losing my marbles here. 
Ubuntu 18.04.2
I have Docker + Portainer installed via a local container. I can access the portainer UI via https://ip-address:9000

However, I also installed napp-it for ZFS management. I am supposed to connect to it on http://ip-address:81, but the connection just times out.

Firewall disabled for testing and still nothing.

```
root@daviserver:~# ufw status
Status: inactive
```

You can see the service running on the last line here

```
root@daviserver:~# lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
systemd      1            root   71u  IPv6  23575      0t0  TCP *:9090 (LISTEN)
rpcbind    907            root    8u  IPv4   2540      0t0  TCP *:111 (LISTEN)
rpcbind    907            root   11u  IPv6   2543      0t0  TCP *:111 (LISTEN)
systemd-r 1446 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4  27356      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN)
sshd      1914            root    3u  IPv4  30011      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd      1914            root    4u  IPv6  30022      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 2219            root    4u  IPv6  30979      0t0  TCP *:9000 (LISTEN)
sshd      3934         stephen    9u  IPv6  40840      0t0  TCP [::1]:6010 (LISTEN)
sshd      3934         stephen   10u  IPv4  40841      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:6010 (LISTEN)
mini-http 4975         napp-it    4u  IPv6  46582      0t0  TCP *:81 (LISTEN)
```

I also installed Cockpit, can see it running on port 9090 and I cannot connect to it either. I am not even sure where else to look at this point.

Comment: Your question is missing the information which services are running in which containers, and you have to tell docker which ports needs to be mapped to which container ports when you start the container. So my first guess would be that you forgot that.

Comment: I shut down all my containers and the issue still persist. From what I understand the docker daemon binds to 0.0.0.0, but it shouldn't bind on every port right?

Comment: When you run docker, are you using the `-p <host port>:<container port>` argument to map the connection into the container's ports?

Comment: Yes I was mapping ports that way. At this point I have uninstalled docker and still have issues. Just going to re-install the OS and start over.